# How can I repair a particle-board dresser after sanding part of it?

Tags: repair

I have a dresser that is painted white with water stains on one end. I sanded and found particle board underneath. I can not get the damage to smooth out over the water stained end. What can I do to refinish it?

Answer (score 1):

Use wood filler to fill and smooth the damaged area.  Then buy a veneer material in the finish you'd like (I think you can find it in the counter department at Lowe's or Home Depot - I saw some there the other day) and apply that to the entire dresser with the manufacturer recommended adhesive.